# Solve infinite integral that includes a staircase-function

Tags: integration

Suppose we have two functions, a smooth function $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and a staircase function, $g(x) = \lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor$. How would we solve for:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)g(x) \,dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{k^2}^{(k+1)^2}ke^{-x}dx = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\left[ -e^{-x}\right]_{x = k^2}^{x=(k+1)^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\left(-e^{-(k+1)^2}+e^{-k^2}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-k^2}.$

As per [Evaluation of $\sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{-x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174877/evaluation-of-sum-x-0-infty-e-x2), we have that the above quantity is $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\vartheta_{3}(0,\frac{1}{e})$.

Comment: Note that $$\vartheta_3(0,x)=\vartheta_3(x)$$ for some definitions.